# How to allow only alphabets in Ionic input text box?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-forms, ionic3

I want to allow only alphabets and spaces to be allowed in ionic input text box.

I tried,

```
<ion-input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" ng-pattern-restrict></ion-input>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: you are working in angular js??

Comment: It is an ionic input text box. I can use angular2

Comment: an alternate way, you can do with validation and regexp.

Comment: @rahulpatel can you please elaborate your comment.